# Is there an application I can run under i3 that lists available desktop applications by category and shows their desktop icons?

Tags: i3, application, menu

I love using i3 but one thing I miss from mainstream desktop environments is that they have menus that class desktop applications by their category and display them in convenient lists. Is an application that does this, or something similar, available for i3? I am aware of dmenu but it lists all commands available and does not distinguish between desktop applications and commands to be issued within a terminal. It also does not group applications by category, nor does it show the desktop icons for applications.

Comment: FWIW, the command `i3-dmenu-desktop` shows only `*.desktop` files.

You can get icons from [rofi](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi) but I don't believe it sorts programs into categories. That'd be a nice RFE.

Answer (score 0):

xfce-appfinder lists `.desktop` files by category and shows icons.

Comment: That's a nice application. I won't replace dmenu with it, but I'll keep it around. Thanks.